# Spring MVC controller's not applied

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple `SpringMVC` example. I have:

`appContext`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
</beans>
```

`web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mywp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

`FirstController.java`:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class FirstController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/mywp/hellact")
    public static String firstAction()
    {
        System.out.println("This is the first controller");
        return "Hello action";
    }
}
```

But when I deploy the compiled war on the `JBoss 7.0.2` and try to get access to `localhost:8080/mywp/hellact` I get a `404` error. There are no any exceptions thrown into the server logs. What's wrong?

The server log:

```
15:03:15,333 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appContext.xml]
15:03:15,543 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
15:03:15,653 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-4) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 390 ms
15:03:15,703 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mywp]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
15:03:15,703 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
15:03:15,703 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Dec 26 15:03
14]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
15:03:15,723 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (MSC service thread 1-4) FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 20 ms
15:03:15,723 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) registering web context: /mywp
15:03:15,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployed "mywp.war"
```

As you can see, there is no any error was occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `<annotation-driven />` annotation

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app"/>
     <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Though, I see by your xsd version that you're using spring-mvc 2.5, if so, the following config should work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

    <bean class="com.mycompany.app.controllers.FirstController "/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `RequestMapping` from :

> @RequestMapping("/mywp/hellact")

To :

> @RequestMapping("/hellact")

You don't need to mention the Name of your WebApp in the `RequestMapping` Value.